# How to write to a text file in a specific path in android device

Tags: android, file, cordova, mobile

I am using visual studio to create cordova mobile application and I'm using `Cordova-plugin-file` for file manipulation on device.
How to write to a text file in a specific path in android device, 
to be able to get it from a fixed location.

Comment: read [this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file)

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?  If you find the answer useful, you can up vote and accept it by click on the up arrow and check mark near the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. Also you can find good explanation for the code in [Cordova Example: Writing to a file](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) & [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

As a very short explanation: you should install cordova file plugin, after device ready, you first will ask for a FileSystem then will create the file in a particular path (in my example:`cordova.file.dataDirectory`) and finally will write to it.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
           window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
               dirEntry.getFile("log.txt", { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

                        fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                            console.log('Write completed.');
                        };

                        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                            console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
                        };

                        // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
                        var blob = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], { type: 'text/plain' });

                        fileWriter.write(blob);

                    }, errorHandler);
                });
            });

 }, false);
```